# Simultaneous observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, observables

Hi I understand that when two observables are simultaneous we can measure them both at the same time without affecting each other however is there a condition that the commutator between the two observables has to meet in order for them to be simultaneous. Also is stating two observables are compatible the same as stating they are simultaneous? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> is there a condition that the commutator between the two observables has to meet

Yes. The commutator must vanish if the two observables can be measured simultaneously. So say for two observables represented by the operators  $A$ and $B$, then $$[A,B]=0$$

> Also is stating two observables are compatible the same as stating they are simultaneous

Actually, it means that they will have simultaneous eigenstates, and that you can simultaneously measure their eigenvalues, where for any operator $$O \psi = o\psi$$
where $o$ is the eigenvalue (the physical quantity corresponding to the observable $O$) and $\psi$ is called the eigenstate.

Comment: Probably worth emphasizingthat the notion of simultaneity here doesn't really depend on physical time, and is not at all the same notion as in e.g. relativity

Comment: Yes. This is a good point. I will edit my answer when time permits.